# Did Dragonball (1/Z/S) ever show the Z fighters getting ready for the day?

Tags: dragon-ball-series, dragon-ball-super, dragon-ball-z, dragon-ball, dragon-ball-manga

It's almost a meaningless question, but I seem to recall such a scene but can't find it.

Edit: Just as regular people do. They tighten their belts, they get dressed (not showing everything of course), they have morning coffee, stuff like that...

Comment: Maybe it is during return of goku or freeza.

Answer (score 1):

There have been multiple instances where the Z Fighters have been shown living their normal lives such as

- Gohan Going to School (After Perfect Cell Saga)
- Gohan Visiting Bulma for His Great Saiyaman Costume (After Perfect Cell Saga)
- Goku Farming When Mr Satan Comes to give him the award money he recieved after he claimed to have defeated Beerus in front of the World (After Battle of Gods Arc in Dragon Ball Super)
- Vegeta, Trunks and Bulma going to the amusement park
- Goku and squad partying when Vegeta's Brother shows up along with his wife to ask for help to fight Abo and Kado
- Bulma's Birthday Party up until Beerus Shows up

And many such examples exist in the series

Comment: @EroSɘnnin okk got it

Comment: @EroSɘnnin I have rewritten the answer accordingly